Insert operations in MySQL causing deadlocks
I created the following table in MySQL:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
uuid VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (uuid)
); 

When I ran multiple threads simultaneously to insert into the table, a deadlock occurred.

msg:Error: 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I am not sure why this is causing a deadlock.
Here is my test Python code:
import threading
import mysql.connector
import uuid
import time

db_config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'database': 'device.db-0',
}

def insert_data(thread_id):
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        sql = """
        INSERT INTO test_table (uuid)
        VALUES (%s)
        """
        cursor.execute(sql, (uuid,))
        connection.commit()
        print(f"Thread {thread_id}: Inserted uuid {uuid}")

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(f"Thread {thread_id}: Error: {err}")

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

threads = []
for i in range(500):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=insert_data, args=(i,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("All threads have finished.")


welcome, if this is a programming question please goto stackoverflow.com, if its Db related then [dba.se] is your friend

What is the value of autocommit?  Do you have "transactions" (BEGIN/START...COMMIT)?  How many threads are you running?

Each thread executes the following commands:
start transaction;
INSERT INTO test_table (uuid) VALUES (%s)
commit;
autocommit   = ON
